# Handling huge numbers of Relations in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, limit, relation, truncated

Im currently using a table ViewedPosts to link my Users and BlogPosts.

As I dont need any of the extra data, and as an experiment on optimisation and bandwidth usage, I'd like to move this to a [Relation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations) column.

This relation column could become very large, lets say MILLIONS of relations.

Lets say I want to have a list of Blogs and I want to know if they have been viewed by the User. I'd need my full set of relations as well as my paginated Blogs, but what if the User has viewed millions of blog posts?

I'm pretty sure Parse will not return millions of relations in a User object, they will simply be truncated.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer, I think, but it could do with little a restatement:  User has a relation called `viewedBlog`.  It gets added-to each time a user views a blog ("blog post" is probably what we mean here), so it can relate to zillions of those.  That's fine since that relation column is like a reference to another table.

When you have a user, you can get its `viewedBlog` relation, and when you from that relation you can get it's `query`.  That query has all the features and limitations of a regular `Parse.Query` (because it is one).

So you can set its limit up to 1k, qualify it further (say, by post tags), sort it (say, descending on recency), and set a skip to page through results.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer could be to do a relational query on two parameters ie:

Get the paginated list of Blogs which match list of Blogs and also appear in the User's viewedBlog relation.